# Can't write string to database after pdf2text conversion

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i am using pdf2text from spatie and actually it works fine. The Problem: When i try to to write the text (return value of the pdf2text function) from the converted pdf it always throws me a an error **Illuminate\Database\QueryException**. After analyzing the problem it turned out it was caused by the insert query. I can't directly insert the converted string to the database. When i `dd();` the output and copy it manually to a variable and insert it to database it works fine. The return type of the pdftotext function is also a string. I tried to convert it again to a string but it was a redundant step as expected. When i try to pass text to the view it also gives me nothing. No output of the screen only `dd();` and `print_r();' gives me an output.

Well, thats my code:

Controller:

```
public function TextFromPdf(Request $pdfFile)
{


    if (isset($pdfFile)) {

        $file = $pdfFile->file('pdfFile');
        $fileName =  'PDF File '.time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->storeAs('',$fileName);
        $filePath =  Storage::disk('local')->path($fileName);

        $text = (new Pdf('C:\CV-Test\xpdf-tools-win-4.03\bin64\pdftotext.exe'))
       ->setPdf($filePath)->text();


        DB::table('fulltexts')->insert([

            'text' => $text
        ]);
    
    return view('CV_test.pdf', compact('text'));
}
```

**screenshot of** `dd($text);`

[image: screenshot of dd($text);]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: From your screen dump, there are lots of double quotation marks...... You may wish to escape them before you do the db record saving.

Comment: You think that causes the problem? When i copy them manually and insert them its no problem. Anyway ill try that out. Thanks.

Comment: tried this one: `$text = str_replace('""', '', $text);` dump is still the same. How can i remove the doublequotes ?

Comment: you may use the PHP function `htmlspecialchars` or `addslashes`

Comment: Man i cant manage to get rid of the **b"""** at the beginning and **"""** at the end. Everything in between can be removed i tried your suggestions and even trim but not working. The strange thing i can insert exactly the same string manually with **b"""** and the **"""** at the end. I eve tried another pdf it has again that letter with the double quotes and the content is in between. I have no clue what to do. :(( It cant be so difficult. Am i just too dump :( I dont know whay i cant insert it to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found out what it was, it took some time. The character **b** bevor the string quotes means its a **binary string**. When i tried to insert it to database it was not working because my database was'nt able to manage binary strings. I just had to convert it to utf8
by `utf8_encode($binary_string)`, then i could write it to the database without any problems